# Using the "&oplus;" HTML code displays literally &oplus; on my DT

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, dt

I am generating a custom datatable and I want to hide a list that is displayed after clicking on a + and hidden again clicking on the -.
It works, but the table would display literally the ⊕ code until interaction with it, then it is the - and +.

Has this happened to anyone else?

Thanks

[First display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr5NI.png)

[Then after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjo9b.png)

[After second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV67Q.png)

**Thank you in advance.**

**The code:**

```
datatable2 <- function(x, vars = NULL, opts = NULL, ...) {
  names_x <- names(x)
  if (is.null(vars))
    stop("'vars' must be specified!")
  pos <- match(vars, names_x)
  if (any(map_chr(x[, pos], typeof) == "list"))
    stop("list columns are not supported in datatable2()")
  pos <- pos[pos <= ncol(x)] + 1
  rownames(x) <- NULL
  if (nrow(x) > 0)
    x <- cbind(` ` = "&oplus;", x)
  if(dim(x)[2]==7){
      js <- c("function(row, data) {",
                "if (data[5]>1000 | data[5]<1){",
                "$('td:eq('+(4)+')', row).html(data[5].toExponential(3));",
                "}",
                "}")
  }else if(dim(x)[2]==9){
      js <- c("function(row, data) {",
                "if (data[6]>1000 | data[6]<1){",
                "$('td:eq('+(5)+')', row).html(data[6].toExponential(3));",
                "}",
                "}")
  }
  opts <- c(opts,
            list(
              columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,pos)),
                                list(orderable = FALSE,
                                     className = "details-control", targets = 1),
                                list(className = "dt-left", targets = 1:2),
                                list(className = "dt-right",targets = 3:ncol(x) 
                                     )
                                ),
              lengthMenu = list(c(10,25,50,100,-1), c(10,25,50,100,"All")),
              rowCallback = JS(js),
              buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
              dom = "Bfrtilp"
              ) )
  datatable(x, ..., extensions = "Buttons", options = opts, 
            callback = JS(.callback2(x = x, pos = c(0, pos) ) ) )
}


.callback2 <- function(x, pos = NULL) {
    part1 <- "table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});"
    part2 <- .child_row_table2(x, pos = pos)
    part3 <- "
   table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
    var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      row.child.hide();
      td.html('&oplus;');
    } else {
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      td.html('&ominus;');
    }
  });"
    paste(part1, part2, part3)
}


.child_row_table2 <- function(x, pos = NULL) {
    names_x <- paste0(names(x), ":")
    text <- "var format = function(d) {
    text = '<div><table >' +"
    for (i in seq_along(pos)) {
        text <- paste(text, glue::glue("'<tr>' +
          '<td>' + '{names_x[pos[i]]}' + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + d[{pos[i]}] + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' + "))
    }
    paste0(text, "'</table></div>'
      return text;};")
}
```

Comment: Just a comment: you could use [this method](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DT_childTables.html) for child tables.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try, Stéphane Laurent :)